# Keras (+tensorflow) cannot predict with only part of the sequential

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am now working on building a stereo matching network using Keras with tensorflow as backend. The network has the following structure:

[image]

After training the whole network, I need to test it. However, training phase and testing phase are quite different. I have to split the model into two parts. The first part is CNN+Concatenate which only needs to be run once, while the fully-connected part (actually I modify it to be fully-conv form when testing) needs to be run for d times with slightly different input, where d varies from 100 to 228.

The first part network code:

```
# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = X1.shape[0], X1.shape[1]
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
X1 = X1.reshape(1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
X2 = X2.reshape(1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)

# number of conv filters to use
nb_filters = 112

# CNN kernel size
kernel_size = (3,3)

left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same', input_shape=input_shape))
left_branch.add(Activation('relu'))
left_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same'))
left_branch.add(Activation('relu'))
left_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same'))
left_branch.add(Activation('relu'))
left_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same'))
left_branch.add(Activation('relu'))

right_branch = Sequential()
right_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same', input_shape=input_shape))
right_branch.add(Activation('relu'))
right_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same'))
right_branch.add(Activation('relu'))
right_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same'))
right_branch.add(Activation('relu'))
right_branch.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode='same'))
right_branch.add(Activation('relu')) 
merged = Merge([left_branch, right_branch], mode='concat')

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(merged)
```

I load the weights gained from training phase into the first part of the network and try to get prediction of it.

```
def load_cnn_weights(filepath):
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
    weights = []
    for i in range(1, 9):
        weights.append(f['model_weights/conv2d_{}/conv2d_{}/kernel:0'.format(i, i)][()])
        weights.append(f['model_weights/conv2d_{}/conv2d_{}/bias:0'.format(i, i)][()])
    f.close()
    return weights

weights = load_cnn_weights("/home/users/shixin.li/segment/Lecun_stereo_rebuild/weights.hdf5") 
cnn.set_weights(weights)
output_cnn = cnn.predict([X1, X2])
```

I already check that the weights are read successfully and can fit into the network according to calling `get_weights()` function. X1 and X2 are not zero, they are normalized gray scale image matrix. I even tried compile the network before predict. But the result `output_cnn` gives all zero.

I didn't see anyone have this problem and I am stuck for two days. The part which really confuses me is that the input and weights are all not zero, then why the result is zero? If you could help, I would really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) to find out exactly what the inputs to the op with all-zero outputs are, to try to understand what is going on.